# Reopen overlay after hiding Jquery

Tags: jquery, overlay

the problem i'm having is that when I click on the imagemap menu i've made is that it shows the overlay fine, it also closes it fine when I click on the body. But when i click the imagemap again, it doesn't reopen.

```
    $('.circleLink').click(function() {
        $('#overlay').fadeIn(1000);
        $('#overlay').live("click", function() {
            $(this).fadeOut("slow", function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });

    return false;
    });
```

Comment: can you provide us a fiddle??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the jQuery Documentation:

> the .remove() method takes elements out of the DOM

So you delete the element and -because it isn't there anymore- it can not be faded in anymore.

If you change 'remove()' to 'hide()', it should work.

Answer (score 1):

try

$(this).hide();

instead of

$(this).remove();